# voltage spiking due to strong gate driver

Tags: circuit-design, integrated-circuit, switch-mode-power-supply, power-electronics, gate-driving

If I make the PWM signal to gate very steep ( with rising time `tr` is very small like `200ps`) then at rising time the gate charging current spike is too big, up to `6A` and that current flows to the drain too and make output voltage spike.

Normally how would you solve this?
One possible way is to make gate driver weaker but what else can I do without slowing gate driver?

[image]

Comment: Why can't you slow it down? Is your switching frequency so high you need 200ps rise time?

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope or simulator to show some plots of input PWM and output voltage?

Comment: I don't know what QFOR is for or how you're controlling it, but it seems to me you've made a bit of a boost converter and the voltage spike at the QFRE Drain and at Vout is due to LSTRA dumping it's electromagnetic energy storage each time QFRE turns off, no?

Comment: @Unimportant I want to make it steep to reduce switching loss.

Comment: @GabrielStaples I just took a picture from internet and drew that for illustration only. I haven't made it on pcb yet.

Comment: @anhnha, is that your actual circuit? If not, please edit your question, click the "Schematic" button, and draw your real schematic. Inductors QFOR there will produce a voltage spike whenever the driving current is turned off, so long as it is saturated and a current is already flowing through it.

Comment: @anhnha 200ps only makes sense for +100MHz switching speeds, which is highly unlikely. At a realistic switching speed you can afford far more relaxed rise times. All the hassle and ringing that comes with trying to achieve such insane rise times aren't efficient either.

Comment: Too fast increases losses. Adding a series gate drive resistor (say 10 Ohms) is normal. This both SLOWS drive and helps prevent gate ringing. A reverse biased Schottky diode across FET gs mounted close to the FET also may help.

Comment: @Unimportant how would you calculate that +100MHz from  200ps?

Comment: @anhnha Aiming for around 3% of 1 PWM period for rise and fall times combined is reasonable in most cases.

Answer (score 4):

Gate Driver will not produce 0.2 nanosecond edges.

The required charge must flow from 2nanoHanry to 10nanoHenry inductances in the gate driver's GND, VDD, Vin (03/3v?) and Vout (0/12v?).

Given 2nH and 2nF are SLOW edges ( 60MHz ringing), you should alter your edge rate expectations.

Comment: Gate driver is on-chip. Would that count?